# scroll from fixed width to full screen image

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to figure out how this works.  Appears to be a fixed image and as you scroll, it blows to full screen and a video plays (I want to leave it as the image), then, you can scroll content in it.  Once the content ends, the image scrolls up.  Works in reverse too!

Scroll about half way down the page: https://www.dji.com/mavic-mini?site=brandsite&from=homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice the code, the video is in full-screen size. The Developer created a mask frame overlay over the video, which animates away on scroll event. Pretty sleek move :)

[image]

[image]

Also the video is made in such a way that the target elements are centered for the frame crop.